# Google Pay Request failed An unexpected error has occurred Please try again later [R_BIBED_07] errors

Tags: flutter, google-pay, stripes

{
"provider": "google_pay",
"data": {
"environment": "PRODUCTION",
"apiVersion": 2,
"apiVersionMinor": 0,
"allowedPaymentMethods": [
{
"type": "CARD",
"tokenizationSpecification": {
"type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
"parameters": {
"gateway": "stripe",
"stripe:version": "2020-08-27",
"stripe:publishableKey":""
}
},
"parameters": {
"allowedCardNetworks": ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"],
"allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
"billingAddressRequired": false,
"billingAddressParameters": {
"format": "FULL",
"phoneNumberRequired": false
}
}
}
],
"merchantInfo": {
"merchantId": "demo@gmail.com",
"merchantName": "KABATASA"
},
"transactionInfo": {
"totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
"totalPrice": "12.34",
"currencyCode": "AED"
}

```
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this??

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you solve it? @Gunvant Murge

Comment: is your gpay business Active?